# Reformatting data using Access + Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, reformat

I'm trying to reformat data in MS Access as the number of rows exceeds what Excel can do. However, this is my first attempt with subqueries, and could do with some assistance in what I should be doing.

I have data that looks like the following:

```
t, id, x
1, 10, 1
1, 20, 5
1, 30, 10
2, 10, 2
2, 20, 7
2, 30, 14
```

and I'm trying to mung it into this order:

```
id, t1, t2, x1, x2
10, 1,  2,  1,  2
20, 1,  2,  5,  7
30, 1,  2,  10, 14
... 
10, 70, 71, 66, 68
```

etc.

The data presented are distances and time values -- so I want to reformat the above to then calculate speed through (x2 - x1) / (t2 - t1).

Is this something that Access can assist with? I'm not too fussed about having to use multiple tables / queries to get to the end result... Just so long as I get there!!!

Comment: here @ SO we help, but what do you have so far?

Comment: So far, mostly logic!! Here are my initial thoughts:

(1.) Sort the data by id, then t
(2.) If the id value at t+1 does not equal the id value at t, this should give the values for t2 and x2
(3.) If the id value at t-1 does not equal the id value at t, this should give the values for t1 and x1

Does my logic stand up to scrutiny?

Comment: Are they always odd and even e.g. t = 1 paired with t = 2.. t = 69 with t = 70?

Comment: That looks very like a crosstab query to me.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The pairings are not always odd and even, but will not equal one another. E.g. on rows 1 through 5, the t value could be 1, but on rows 6 through 12 the t value could be 7. Make sense?

Comment: Some more data please Join t=1 to t = t + 1 is doable, but that would do t = 2 to t = 3 as well, if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

create a crosstab query from your original data... then use another query to select from the crosstab query into another table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the data to itself and get t1 and x1 from the left of the join and t2 and x2 from the right, the trick is in the join.

First the sample data doesn't really cover enough cases to see what's really required, so I'm inferring and guessing...

- at time t you record the progress x for some ids, and you want to work out dx/dt for each interval
- t increments each time, but not necessarily by one
- t is going to be unique for each id
- x will come as it comes.

First I need the rows [ranked](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=208946) sequentially

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Table1
        WHERE [t] < [t1].[t]+1 AND id = t1.id;
    ) AS Rank
    , *
FROM
    Table1 AS t1;
```

Call this Query1 and

```
SELECT 
      a.id AS id
    , a.t AS t1
    , b.t AS t2
    , a.x AS x1
    , b.x AS x2
    , (b.x - a.x) / (b.t - a.t) as Speed
FROM
    Query1 as a
        INNER JOIN
    Query1 as b
        ON
                a.id = b.id 
            AND (a.rank + 1) = b.rank
```

and bob's your uncle

Answer (score 0):

Can you use sql server? Or are you just trying to do this with just using Access/Excel?  You can possibly do this with TextPad macro as well if you want to get real simple and creative... especially if the rows are consistently in that order.